# Getting errors when trying to import pymc

Tags: python, linux, pymc

I have installed pymc using `easy_install pymc` command. While I try to import the package using `import pymc`.

I am getting following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-2.3.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pymc/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .CommonDeterministics import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-2.3.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pymc/CommonDeterministics.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import safe_len, stukel_logit, stukel_invlogit, logit, invlogit, value, find_element
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-2.3.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pymc/utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import flib
ImportError: libatlas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04` and `Python 2.7`.

What is the reason for these errors?

Comment: You can find some insights [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52703/using-atlas-from-scipy).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing that missing library:

`apt-get install libatlas3-base-dev`

Comment: My Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have a `libatlas3-base-dev`, rather it's got `libatlas-base-dev`. See the link in my comment to the question for tips on how to fix this if you DO have the dev libraries installed.